# How to cast DbSet<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, entity-framework-6

Given the following simplified Entity Framework 6 context, I am trying to populate a List with the entities but having problems with how to cast (I believe) via reflection.

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
   public virtual IDbSet<FooClass> Foo { get; set; }    
   //...
}

public class FooClass
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    //...    
}

public main()
{
     using (var context = new FooContext())
     {
         var sets = typeof(FooContext).GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsInterface && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().ToString().ToLower().Contains("idbset"));

         foreach (var set in sets)
         {
             //When I debug and enumerate over 'value' the entire results are shown so I believe the reflection part is OK.
             var value = set.GetValue(context, null);

             //Always returns null. How can I cast DbSet<T> to List<object> or List<T>? 
             var list = value as List<object>();

             //...
         }
     }
}
```

I'm doing this for utility method for some integration testing I am doing. I am trying to do this without using direct inline SQL calls (using SqlConnection and SqlCommand etc) to access the database (as the datastore may change to Oracle etc).

Comment: You can cast to `IEnumerable` interface

Comment: `set.GetValue(context, null)` returns an `object`.You're trying to cast it to `List<object>`.

Comment: A `DbSet<>` *is not a list*, and neither a `DbSet<Foo>` nor a `List<Foo>` is a `List<object>`. What you are trying to do is doomed. Can you clarify your intent? What is it that you want to *do*?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh well, to be fair, that would work *if it was one*

Comment: `DbSet<T>` doesn't inherit from `List<T>` or `List<object>` so you can't just cast it.  Why do you want a list?  Why not just enumerate the `DbSet<T>`?  Why are you using reflection anyway?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you using reflection on a `DbSet`?

Comment: DbSet{T} implements IEnumerable{T}. List{T} has a constructor which takes an IEnumerable{T}, so you could just do `new List<T>(dbSet)`

Comment: Your type check should probably be `pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDbSet<>)`

Comment: @Lee note you must check `IsGenericType` before calling that

Comment: @MarcGravell - Thanks, forgot about that.

Comment: Doing "as IEnumerable<object>" works. FYI the purpose of the integration test is for testing the repository. Inside the repository it using EF6 which in this case is connecting to SQL. However it in the future it could change to Oracle or XML or whatever. I am basically doing lots of integration tests that ensure that values passed into the repository (Creates, Updates or deletes) are 1) getting updated in the database. (as the models I have are quiet complex) 2) only the relevant fields on the entity getting saved are getting edited 3) That no unexpected changes are happening to other entitie

Comment: Doing it dynamically via reflection saves tying my unit tests too closely to my actual implementation. Also I cant access the context.ChangeTracker because its inside the repository. I also dont want to Shim this out via Microsoft Fakes as it is OTT.

Answer (score 14):

IDBSet inherits from `IQueryable<TEntity>`, `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, `IQueryable`, and `IEnumerable`, so you can't directly cast it to a list that way.
You could get a `List<TEntity>` of all entities in the `DBSet` though by using `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync()`

THis creates a copy of all entities in memory though, so you should consider operating with LINQ directly on the DBSet

Comment: This gets you a `SqlNullValueException`

Answer (score 12):

```
//dont forget using System.Linq;
using (var context = new FooContext())
{
   IQueryable<FooClass> rtn = from temp  in context.Foo select temp;
   var list = rtn.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I had a parsing error trying to retreive all elements in a table. Sending a list instead of a "IQueryable" solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Alongside VicYam's answer, here is an easier way with a detailed explanation.

Once you add the `System.Linq` namespace, you no longer need to get `IQueryable` and then convert to a `List`. Instead, you will get the extension methods on the `DbSet` object.

What does this mean? You can simply return the `DbSet` by itself as it inherits from `IEnumerable`. The consumer, possibly a dev, can then do a `.ToList` or any other list type they may need.

**Easiest**

This will return the `DbSet` as is, which already inherits from `IEnumerable` which is a list type that can be then converted to a `List`.

```
List<ObjectType> list = new List<ObjectType>();
using (var context = new FooContext())
{
    list = context.Foo;
}
```

**Alternative**

You can immediately convert from `IEnumerable` to a `List`.

```
using (var context = new FooContext())
{
    var list = context.Foo.ToList();
}
```

**Still want VicYam's answer but as a one line?**

```
using (var context = new FooContext())
{
    var list = context.Foo.AsQueryable().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private StudentDatabaseEntities db = new StudentDatabaseEntities();

public List<StudentDatabaseDbTableModel> AllProducts()
{
    return db.StudentDatabaseDbTableModel.ToList();
}
```

db.StudentDatabaseDbTableModel is of type DbSet. ToList is a method inside DbSet class. ToList method converts object of type DbSet to List type.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: There is no such a `ToList()` method in the DbSet.